# Xcode buttons/images always on top?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Is there an option for a button/image to set, that it will always be shown on top? So I have 2 buttons and want to add an image. But the image covers the two buttons and I have no idea how I could get the image in the background or the buttons in the front.

BTW: I´m fairly new to xcode and programming...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the xCode top menu item Editor->Arrange. There you have options to handle z index for controls.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was, to have two button one for the label and one for the image and when one is clicked it propagates the message to the other and does the action depending on which one was clicked.